# get parent node with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript solution of getting the parentNode from my object. However no matter what I seem to do it keeps saying 'undefined'.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="EmbedImageWidget" ng-if="vm.imageLink == '' || vm.imageLink == 'undefined'">
    <img ng-src="{{ vm.imageUrl }}" />
</div>

<div class="EmbedImageWidget" ng-if="vm.imageLink" >
    <a href="{{vm.imageLink}}" target="_blank">
        <img ng-src="{{ vm.imageUrl }}" />
    </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
var imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName("EmbedImageWidget");
console.log(imageElement);
```

OBJECT
[image]

I have tried using

```
    var imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName("EmbedImageWidget").parentNode;
    console.log(imageElement);

    var imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName("EmbedImageWidget")[0].parentNode;
    console.log(imageElement);
```

[image]

However both options didn't work. Any help will be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: In the HTML you provided, elements with class `EmbedImageWidget` don't seem to have parent nodes.

Comment: Can you include an example on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: It is because they are being injected from another file. I uploaded a new image that shows this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName("EmbedImageWidget")[0].parentNode` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("EmbedImageWidget").parentNode` .This code is working fine [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3jamc9f1/)

---

But I think you want to access Image element and that is not parent of div . That is child of that div instead

Comment: The code worked tnaks for the help. I actually have to go 2 levels up outside of my document to remove some padding. That's why I wanted to reach it's parent. anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName("EmbedImageWidget")[0].parentNode;
console.log(imageElement);
```

this is the best solution, but there is some problem, your `img` element generated after running your js code. when you try to get parent node of `img` element in js, there is no `img` element with `EmbedImageWidget` class.

it's because of `ng-if`.

Comment: if you try `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("EmbedImageWidget").length);` you can find out there is no objected related to your selector.

Comment: If you look at his JS block, he is logging the call to `getElementsByClassName`, and it is outputting at least 1 element.  We can even see from his photo that it has a `parentNode` accessor, which is not `undefined`

Comment: do you test `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("EmbedImageWidge‌​t").length);` ???